# generate last day of the month from month -year in python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Convert object to with month_year to last date of the month

How to generate a new column with last date of the month from month_year? Month_year is an object and I am not able to convert it to date format in python. I want last date to be in date format so that I can calculate difference with other date columns available in the data.

Data is as follows:

```
id   month_date
id_1 04-2018
id_1 04-2018
id_2 04-2018
id_2 05-2019
```

Desired output:

```
id   month_date  last_date
id_1 04-2018    30-4-2018
id_1 04-2018    30-4-2018
id_2 04-2018    30-4-2018
id_2 05-2019    31-5-2019
```

Comment: Are using `pandas`?

Comment: yes, its a pandas dataframe on which i want to make these changes. if i check dtype for month_year columns I am getting object and not able to perform any date realted caluations for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_timestamp.html) with [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for remove times:

```
df['last_date'] = df['month_date'].dt.to_timestamp(how='end').dt.floor('d')
print (df)
     id month_date  last_date
0  id_1    2018-04 2018-04-30
1  id_1    2018-04 2018-04-30
2  id_2    2018-04 2018-04-30
3  id_2    2019-05 2019-05-31
```

Another solution:

```
df['last_date'] = df['month_date'].dt.to_timestamp() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
print (df)
     id month_date  last_date
0  id_1    2018-04 2018-04-30
1  id_1    2018-04 2018-04-30
2  id_2    2018-04 2018-04-30
3  id_2    2019-05 2019-05-31
```

EDIT:

Another solutions:

```
df['last_date1'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['month_date']).to_timestamp(how='end').floor('d')
df['last_date2'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['month_date']).to_timestamp() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
print (df)
     id month_date last_date1 last_date2
0  id_1    2018-04 2018-04-30 2018-04-30
1  id_1    2018-04 2018-04-30 2018-04-30
2  id_2    2018-04 2018-04-30 2018-04-30
3  id_2    2019-05 2019-05-31 2019-05-31
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when i try either of the code -"'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'> is not convertible to datetime"

Comment: @LalithaSundarIyerS - Then solution is simplier, give em some time.

Comment: The month_date column is in time data Period('2018-04', 'M') does not match format '%m-%Y' (match) so I changed i tto reflect %Y-%m

Comment: @LalithaSundarIyerS - Answer was edited, please check it.

Comment: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values - new error

Comment: @LalithaSundarIyerS - What is `print (type(df['month_date'].iat[0]))` ?

Comment: its <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'>

Comment: How working if change `df['month_date'].dt.to_timestamp()` to `pd.Index(df['month_date']).to_timestamp()` ?

Comment: or to `pd.PeriodIndex(df['month_date']).to_timestamp()`

Comment: Awesome !!! it workes... Thanks a bunch jezrael . I used "output['last_date'] = pd.Index(output['month_year']).to_timestamp()+ pd.offsets.MonthEnd()

Comment: @LalithaSundarIyerS - I think it seems use some oldier pandas version.

Answer (score 0):

Please add date part as 1st of the month. Like Jan-2019 will be 01-Jan-2019, then using datetime.timedelta , add one month and subtract 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MonthEnd`

**Ex:**

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
df = pd.DataFrame({"month_date": ["04-2018", "04-2018", "04-2018", "05-2019"]})
df["month_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["month_date"], format="%m-%Y")
df["last_date"] = (df["month_date"] + MonthEnd(1)).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
df["month_date"] = df["month_date"].dt.strftime("%m-%Y")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  month_date   last_date
0    04-2018  30-04-2018
1    04-2018  30-04-2018
2    04-2018  30-04-2018
3    05-2019  31-05-2019
```

Comment: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'> is not convertible to datetime.. i am getting this error